# Selenium Webdriver can't find table elements

Tags: c#, selenium, selenium-webdriver, selenium-chromedriver

I'm new with selenium, I can not figure out how to find some elements from an HTML page.
I reproduced the page here :

http://www.ladiana.it/test/test.htm

I need to click on this button :
[Selection](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ciSLA.png)
and after the table appears, to read and write their values :

[values](https://i.stack.imgur.com/P57kN.png)

I'm using c# and I tried all possible way, I also tried to list all the elements with the Id
: "targetDemandReductionMW"

IList IWebElement> all = driver2.FindElements(By.Id("targetDemandReductionMW"));

I get a list of 52 void elements.

Here some other code , it doesn't generate any error but didn't work:

```
 IWebElement element_xpath = driver2.FindElement(By.ClassName("tab_buttonSel"));
        element_xpath.Click();
        IWebElement table = driver2.FindElement(By.Id("drr1OfferAM"));
        
       
          var rows = table.FindElements(By.TagName("tr"));


       
        int conteggio = 0;
            foreach (var row in rows)
           {
                var rowTds = row.FindElements(By.TagName("td"));
                foreach (var td in rowTds)
                {
                    IWebElement a = td.FindElement(By.XPath("//*[@id='targetDemandReductionMW']"));
                Console.WriteLine(conteggio++.ToString()+" "+a.GetAttribute("href")+" "+ a.Text);
                
                     

                }
            }
```

Any help?
Thanks

Comment: Please include the code you've tried.

Comment: I did , i edited the post

Answer (score 1):

For the button you need to click, you can use:

```
//div[@id='tabContainer']/div[2]/following::tr/td[text()='DRR1 Offer']
```

For the xpath for the table records you can use:

```
//table[@id='drr1OfferPMHead']//td[@id='targetDemandReductionMW']
```

This returns the 13 rows that you are looking for. You can then do FindElements on this and get a list.

```
           List<String> search = new List<string>();
        IReadOnlyList<IWebElement> cells = driver.FindElements(By.Xpath("//table[@id='drr1OfferPMHead']//td[@id='targetDemandReductionMW']"));
        foreach (IWebElement cell in cells)
        {
            search.Add(cell.Text);
            
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

The cell (in the html)  has cellclick event , but if i try with :

```
  foreach (IWebElement cell in cells)
        {
            search.Add(cell.Text);
            if (cell.Text=="300.0")
               {
                cell.click();   
               }


        }
```

it come out this error : "OpenQA.Selenium.ElementNotInteractableException: 'element not interactable"

Comment: Once you have an answer for a question that works, accept the answer. Create another thread for new questions. To iterate through a table, try this answer. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61681297/proceed-to-each-link-with-specific-text-in-html-table/61684507#61684507 Keep in mind though that you want to find the unique element on the row. In this case it would be your Hour Ending. Find that and then click the value in the row.